# Problem with click audio challenge recaptcha v2 by using selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I am working on website that contain two recaptcha v2, First one solved perfect but the next one open captcha frame but cant click the audio button. I have tried more than method to click the button of audio challenge but i cant get any solution.

[image]

.html:

```
<iframe title="reCAPTCHA" src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/anchor?ar=1&amp;k=6LcMzpsUAAAAAD2JOVSS9DYyk7aSbk-KQ3KL7Nkv&amp;co=aHR0cHM6Ly9tdXFlZW0uc2E6NDQz&amp;hl=ar-ly&amp;type=image&amp;v=Q_rrUPkK1sXoHi4wbuDTgcQR&amp;theme=light&amp;size=normal&amp;cb=flmxkon1yi8a" width="304" height="78" role="presentation" name="a-fzpsv3rm6omy" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" sandbox="allow-forms allow-popups allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-top-navigation allow-modals allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox" cd_frame_id_="6857a4b8282493a9397ca67d60e7e461"></iframe>
```

.py:

```
 frames = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("iframe")
    driver.switch_to.frame(frames[0])
    delay()
    # click on checkbox to activate recaptcha
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/span/div[1]').click()

    # switch to recaptcha audio control frame
    html = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('html')
    html.send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)

    driver.switch_to.default_content()
    frames = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[4]").find_elements_by_tag_name("iframe")
    driver.switch_to.frame(frames[1])
    delay()
    # click on audio challenge
    driver.find_element_by_id("recaptcha-audio-button").click()
```

I tried to change |driver.switch_to.frame(frames[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdyFv.png))| from 0 to 7 but still cant click the button and show me this error:

```
driver.switch_to.frame(frames[1])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Any kind of help please?

Answer (score 1):

See you are using `tagname`, for `iframe`. so why don't you directly try, `find_elements` with `tag_name` ?

instead of this :

```
frames = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[4]").find_elements_by_tag_name("iframe")
```

do this :

```
all_iframes = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("iframe")
```

and then print the size of this `list`,

```
print(len(all_iframes ))
```

and see if it has something then iterate otherwise you will end up getting `IndexError: list index out of range`

The below loop is just for testing :-

```
for iframe in all_iframes:
    print(iframe.text)
```

Comment: he print number 5

Comment: try to print the loop which I have given you above, and let me know the output.

Comment: He shows number length = 5 and print 5 empty rows !